# Can't connect to a recently created, publicly accessible RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just created an empty RDS instance. I want to test out how I would connect to it from any computer in the world.

As far as I can tell I created a VPC with an attached internet gateway and DNS resolution (otherwise the database creation would not let me go in with the publicly accessible option set to Yes).

The RDS instance is for MySQL. I have the admin user and password. When I want to connect to it from my computer, it takes a really long while and comes back with this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '[aws-rds-endpoint]' (115)
```

Here is a image of the current configuration.

[image: RDS main configuration]

And here is an image of the security rules of the security group attached:

[image: Security groups]

As far as I can tell the only rule is "let everything in".

Can anyone help me out?

[UPDATE] One of the comments told me to put the results of nmap up. So here it is:

```
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-18 12:46 -03
Nmap scan report for [aws-rds-endpoint] (x.xx.63.14)
Host is up.
rDNS record for x.xx.63.14: [aws-rds-endpoint]

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.36 seconds
```

Comment: Double check that DNS is resolving (e.g. `dig $HOSTNAME`), and if that resolves correctly, then port scan the endpoint (`nmap -PN -p 3306 $HOSTNAME`)

Comment: @DanielScott I did what you asked. The state seems to be filtered. Which I assume is the problem. It's been a while since I used nmap but I believe it should list either listening or open, right?

Comment: Was the RDS database launched in a Public Subnet or a Private Subnet?

Comment: Yes, it should be open. Did you double check the subnet? Did the `dig` resolve to a public or private IP address?